# How to relay packet in a wireless ad hoc network?

Tags: iptables, wifi, route, multicast

I am trying to connect several Linux computers in wireless ad-hoc multicast :
-computer C1 (192.168.1.3)
-computer C2 (192.168.1.5)
-computer C3 (192.168.1.6)

C1 can not reach C3

On computer C1, using Iperf, I am sending UDP multicast packet to 239.0.0.1

> iperf -c 239.0.0.1 -u -l 1316

On computer C3, using Iperf, I am seeking UDP multicast packet to 239.0.0.1

> iperf -s -u -l 1316 -B 239.0.0.1 --interface wlan0
>   This is a version of Iperf upgraded for multicast.
>   [http://www.amazon.com/dp/0201746123/?tag=stackoverfl08-20](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201746123)

How should I configure those three computers ? Should I change address ? Use route ? Use Iptables ? Set the card in Repeater Mode ?

What is the simplest technique to do ?

Answer (score 0):

If two of the computers connect to the third as a common access point, then turn the third computer into the Gateway for the ad-hoc network.  For instance if C1 is the computer that C2 and C3 are connected to, then set the IP Address of C1 to 192.168.1.1 and then keep C2 and C3 at what they are.

On C1 setup IPv4 Forwarding

On C2 and C3 set the IP you have set C1 to as the Gateway

If the routing tables on C2 and C3 don't update do `route add -net 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.1.1 iface <wireless interface>`

And since you have IP Forwarding enabled, then the packets should redirect to the proper destination.

*Disclaimer: Half-asleep when writing this*